# Determining the Galois group of a quotient of a splitting field and the rationals.

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

I need help verifying if the proof is correct. Usually I think it is right, but always get it wrong:

Let $f(x)=x^4+ax^2+1$ for some $a\in \mathbb{Q}$, and assume that $f(x)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$. Let $M$ be the splitting field for $f(x)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. Determine Gal$(M/\mathbb{Q})$

*proof*: Let $G=\text{Gal}(M/\mathbb{Q})$ and $\pm
\alpha$, $\pm \beta$ be the four roots of $f(x)$. Then we have that $$f(x)=x^4+ax^2+1=(x+\alpha)(x-\alpha)(x+\beta)(x-\beta)=x^4-(\alpha^2+\beta^2)x^2+\alpha^2\beta^2$$ which implies that $\alpha^2+\beta^2=a$ and $\alpha^2\beta^2=1$.We claim that: $$G\cong V\,\,\,\,\,\text{iff} \,\,\,\, \alpha\beta\in \mathbb{Q}$$ where $V$ is the klein-4 group. WLOG let $\alpha\beta$ be positive and note that the Galois closure of $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ is $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\beta)$, but $\beta^2\in \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$, so $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\beta):\mathbb{Q}]=4$. Now $$\sqrt{D}=-4\alpha\beta(\alpha^2-\beta^2)=-4[(\alpha^2+\beta^2)^2-4\alpha^2\beta^2]=-4(a^2-4).$$ So then we have that $\sqrt(D)\in \mathbb{Q}$ ($D$ discriminate of the field) iff $1=\alpha\beta$. However $\sqrt{D}\in\mathbb{Q}$ implies that $G\leq A_4$, but the only group of oder 4 in $A_4$ is $V$, the klein-4 group and this is the only possible case as $\alpha^2\beta^2=1$ implies that $\alpha\beta=1$ as $\alpha\beta$ is positive by assumption. So we have that $$G\cong V$$

Any verfication and help woulod be much appreciated.

Comment: Yet once again, an aged mathematician with failing eyesight puts a request out into the ether: Please do not ever use both “$a$” and “$\alpha$” in the same question, and *especially* in the same equation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here’s the way I look at the equation $X^4+aX^2+1$:

Let $\xi$ be one of its roots. Then you see that the full set of roots is $\{ \xi,\frac1\xi,-\xi,-\frac1\xi\}$. I think  that you can see equally well that your group $V$ acts on these in the obvious way, and you can even deduce what the three intermediate fields are, between $\Bbb Q$ and $M$.